# 'invalid use of const_cast' after compiler update, why?

Tags: c++, callback

I have a piece of code that I can't no longer compile after I've upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. My compiler g++ was updated from 6.3.0 to 7.2.0.

I haven't touched the code, but I can't figure out why it doesn't compile any more.

```
void MessageBus::removeListener(std::function<Message*(Message*)> listener)
{
    // For every registered message listener
    for(auto it = listeners.begin(); listeners.size() && it != listeners.end(); it++) {
        auto registeredListener = it->target<Message*(Message*)>();
        // If the current std::function::target is the same as the one that the caller wants to remove
        if(registeredListener == listener.target<Message*(Message*)>())
            // Remove it from the listener list
            listeners.erase(it);
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
                 from MessageBus.h:6,
                 from MessageBus.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h: In instantiation of ‘_Functor* std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::target() [with _Functor = MyNamespace::Message*(MyNamespace::Message*); _Res = MyNamespace::Message*; _ArgTypes = {MyNamespace::Message*}]’:
MessageBus.cpp:25:70:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:733:9: error: invalid use of const_cast with type ‘MyNamespace::Message* (*)(MyNamespace::Message*)’, which is a pointer or reference to a function type
  return const_cast<_Functor*>(__func);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

MessageBus.cpp:25 is the line `auto registeredListener = it->target<Message*(Message*)>();`

The std::function::target is always a method like the following `Message* Foo::bar(Message*)` in case that wasn't clear.

Why isn't this compiling any more?

Comment: You should have a `return` or a `break` after doing the `erase`, because that operation invalidates your `it` iterator.  But I'd suggest taking a page out of the C# playbook for the .NET event structure, and have the listeners container be treated as an value object (i.e., immutable).

Comment: That being said, your code snippet isn't compilable.  I cannot reproduce the problem you are encountering.  Could you make a small, complete, compilable example that trips the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if std::function contains an actual function, the type parameter for the target() function has to be a function pointer as opposed to a function signature.

In your case, this should compile:

```
it->target<Message*(*)(Message*)>();
```

However, I think the type parameter has to match the actual type contained by the std::function. So if the std::function contains a functor created by std::bind() or a lambda, and you call target() with the type parameter being a function pointer, it will return zero.

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Message;

struct A
{
    Message* f(Message* m) { return m; };
};

Message* f(Message* m) { return m; };

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    A a;
    auto functor = std::bind(&A::f, a, _1);
    std::function<Message*(Message*)> functorF(functor);
    std::function<Message*(Message*)> functionF(&f);
    auto t1 = functionF.target<Message*(*)(Message*)>();
    std::cout << "Function as function pointer: " << (t1 != 0) << std::endl;
    auto t2 = functorF.target<Message*(*)(Message*)>();
    std::cout << "Functor as function pointer: " << (t2 != 0) << std::endl;
    auto t3 = functorF.target<decltype(functor)>();
    std::cout << "Functor as functor: " << (t3!= 0) << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
Function as function pointer: 1
Functor as function pointer: 0
Functor as functor: 1
```

I suspect your call to target() always returned zero with GCC 6.3.0 and therefore the potential bug with the invalidated iterator that Eljay pointed out never happened.

Answer (score 0):

Until gcc-10, the implementation of `std::function::target()` in libstdc++ was

```cpp
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    template<typename _Functor>
      _Functor*
      function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
      target() noexcept
      {
    const function* __const_this = this;
    const _Functor* __func = __const_this->template target<_Functor>();
    return const_cast<_Functor*>(__func);
      }
```

`Message*(Message*)` is a function type, invoking `target<Tp>()` will express `const_cast<Tp*>`, such conversion is ill-formed when `Tp` is a function type.

See [expr.const.cast]

> [Note 3: Some conversions which involve only changes in cv-qualification cannot be done using const_­cast. For instance, conversions between pointers to functions are not covered because such conversions lead to values whose use causes undefined behavior. For the same reasons, conversions between pointers to member functions, and in particular, the conversion from a pointer to a const member function to a pointer to a non-const member function, are not covered. — end note]

And also [conv.qual]

> [Note 4: Function types (including those used in pointer-to-member-function types) are never cv-qualified ([dcl.fct]). — end note]

Since gcc-11, the implementation has been changed to

```cpp
      template<typename _Functor>
    _Functor*
    target() noexcept
    {
      const function* __const_this = this;
      const _Functor* __func = __const_this->template target<_Functor>();
      // If is_function_v<_Functor> is true then const_cast<_Functor*>
      // would be ill-formed, so use *const_cast<_Functor**> instead.
      return *const_cast<_Functor**>(&__func);
    }
```

However, like other answer said, the value stored in `std::function` can only be the type of pointer to function but not function. That is, such invoking will always return `nullptr` though it can be compiled since gcc-11.